# Download a file from userscloud

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I'm trying to write a code so i can download files from the site www.userscloud.com (for example this one https://userscloud.com/nyp52eufhova).

This site has a Download button that has to be clicked in order to appear another button with the "real" url of the file (this url then appears inside the html code too).

So i thought i should use Selenium and PhantomJS to simulate the click and wrote this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get("https://userscloud.com/nyp52eufhova")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='btn_download']").click()
print (driver.page_source)
```

The problem is that the returned page source doesn't contain the "real" URL. It is as if the button was not clicked.

I have tried to click the button using other elements like class name and id with no success. I also tried to wait with driver.implicitly_wait(10) before getting the page source but the outcome was the same.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a Selenium solution but you actually don't need a browser to grab the file. You can just use requests. I just threw this little thing together. It has two functions - one that grabs the file name and one that grabs the file.

```
# coding: utf-8
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_file_name(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
    file_name = soup.h2.text
    return file_name

def get_zip_from_userscloud(url):
    headers = {
        'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Accept-Language':'da-DK,da;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
        'Cache-Control':'max-age=0',
        'Connection':'keep-alive',
        'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Host':'userscloud.com',
        'Origin':'https://userscloud.com',
        'Referer':url,
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests':1,
        'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36'
    }

    payload = {
        'op':'download2',
        'id':url.split("/")[-1],
        'referer':url,
        'adblock_detected':0,
        'down_script':1
        }

    r = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
    return r.content

url = 'https://userscloud.com/nyp52eufhova'
file_name = get_file_name(url)
content = get_zip_from_userscloud(url)
with open (file_name, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(content)
```

So if you have a bunch of links from userscloud, that you'd iterate on, you'd just put them in a list an say:

```
for url in links_list:
    file_name = get_file_name(url)
    content = get_zip_from_userscloud(url)
    with open (file_name, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(content)
```

Cheers...